# How to count distinct errors in google sheets/excel (NON-SQL)?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

```
Column A (Error.Type) |
(Or any other text)   | Column B (Message)  
> 1                   | #REF!               |
> 1                   | #REF!               | total for error 1 is 2
> 2                   | #DIV/0!             |
> 2                   | "Hello World"       | total for error 2 is 2
> 3                   | "Foobar"            | 
> 3                   | "Something"         |
> 3                   | "Else"              | total for error 3 is 3
```

// the number is based on error.type, there are other columns

grand total i need to return `2 + 2 + 3 = 7`

`=(countif(k:k,k1)>1))` <- this code will return all under conditional formatting
but `=count((countif(k:k,k1)>1)))` is a circular dependency and i don't know why?

Comment: can you clarify which quantity you need and where? Maybe the last formula you mentioned is just in column K?

Comment: Did you try =COUNTIF(A:A,">1") ?

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependency occurs when a formula includes a reference to the cell that holds it. If cell A1, has `=A1` the result is the referred error message

`=count((countif(k:k,k1)>1))` will return the circular dependency error if it's included on any cell on the K column, on any other column it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are needing is the COUNTIFS() formula. For example, the following function will return a TRUE value for all the rows except the ones with >1 and #REF! in your example. Thus, giving you your uniques.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)=1
```

Returning this true value for conditional formatting will make w/e you're needing happen on the Range you have it applied. This is assuming whatever value you need in K isn't really needed.

For distinct counts, you can use a helper column (say somewhere in the far right) like this. It will return 1 for each distinct.

```
|            D                |
=COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)
```

Then this formula will get the total distincts.

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,1)
```